# Avro Schema from Enterprise Architect

Tags: schema, enterprise-architect, avro

I have to generate `Avro` schema from UML. We're using `Enterprise Architect` to model our classes.

Can somebody help with generating Avro Schema files (`*.avsc`) from Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EA does not itself support Avro, and to my knowledge there are no third-party extensions that do either. To build one would likely require a solid week or more of effort, and that's for an EA extension expert like myself. So while I'm confident it could be done, I don't think you'll have much luck finding someone to do it for free.

An alternative might be to model and generate an XML schema, which EA can do, and convert that using [xml-avro](https://github.com/stealthly/xml-avro#xml-avro) or some other conversion tool.

Comment: Luckily I got it, was pretty simple though, after I went through the code generation template.